# Effect of regular PN junction diodes in series with Y caps on EMI circuit of 4 kW 400 V power supply?

Tags: diodes, decoupling-capacitor, emi-filtering, leakage-current

I have to add diode in series with Y-cap on EMI to solve some other problem. I took this decision based on assumption EMI test will be for frequencies 150 kHz and more, for this  frequency diode effect is near zero, diode will act as capacitor at this frequency. So according to me this should not be a problem with EMI test. and prelim test shows this works and didnt get bad EMI results because of the addition of the diode.
Has anyone used diode in series with Y caps, or knows in depth other effect (good or bad) by doing this? Any theories that says this is bad?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The diode will behave like a 10 pF cap at high frequencies, so at high frequencies it would be the same as placing a 10 pF cap from ground to the other capacitors.

At middle frequencies to DC (below the filter pole of all the caps and the load) the diodes will start to conduct and those effects are not easy to analyse. I would just go with the resistors.